# Identifying Subaru speedo stepper motor

Tags: subaru

This stepper motor runs the 2007 Subaru Forester (among other models) speedometer gauge. I can't find any info about it on the internet. I need to replace it because it is broken. I have tested it extensively and it is shorted.

I am hoping someone could point me to a replacement source.

The only markings on it are 7201B23 (or maybe Z201B23) on the case and 6923 on the plastic.

The picture shows the motor removed from its metallic casing.

[image]

Comment: I'd contact Sacer, who seem to have stepper motors for many vehicles. https://www.sacer-shop.com